# Replacing string in a column mysql

Tags: mysql

I have this table with some data in it, what I want to do is to replace every "weekdays' from the date and just keep the hour. date has value 'Saturday-13:00' I want '13:00'.

I manage to do it with simple

```
update table_name set date = 'hour' where date = 'weekday-hour';
```

This seems redundant and I was hoping if there is a faster way to doing this. Also I obviously will make a procedure that will do it, but thinking about looping each weekdays and time from 00:00-23:00 seems like a LOT of work.

I found about REPLACE but idk if I'm using correctly.

[image: sample]

Comment: The arguably easiest way is writing 7 queries which will simply strip off all weekdays plus the dash using REPLACE. So you're on the right track.

Comment: Re: "idk if I'm using correctly." You need to post what you're doing so we can tell if you're doing it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to find the `-` before the time and return everything to the right of that. Some examples:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('Friday-1:00', '-', -1);
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('Saturday-16:00', '-', -1)
```

Output:

```
1:00
16:00
```

To update the table, you would use this query:

```
UPDATE table_name SET `date` = SUBSTRING_INDEX(`date`, '-', -1)
```

Comment: If I need to sum all of the count where the date = 'date' for a specific business, how can i use SUM() to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to try something new than replace, you could just do right(column name, 5)

Comment: Sorry, I meant 5 instead of 4

Comment: Edit the answer instead of commenting.